# How does this factoring work?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, factoring

$$ (z^2 - 2i ) = (z -1 -i)(z + 1 +i) $$

I see if you multiply out the right-hand side, you obtain the left-hand side, but how does one know to factor like that or this?

$$ (z^2 − 3iz − 3 + i) = (z − 1 − i)(z + 1 − 2i) $$

Comment: There is a formula for square roots of a complex number: if $\sqrt{\ }$ is the usual real square root, $$z^2=a+bi\iff z=\begin{cases}\pm\sqrt{a}&\text{if }b=0\wedge a\ge 0\\\pm i\sqrt{a}&\text{if }b=0\wedge a<0\\\pm\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a}{2}}+i\dfrac{b}{\lvert b\rvert}\sqrt{\dfrac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a}{2}}\right)&\text{if }b\ne 0\end{cases}$$ and you can work on quadratic polynomials with the same methods you used in the real case. For instance, for the first question you can use $a=0,\ b=2$ and get $(\pm(1+i))^2=2i$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one
is using
$z^2-a^2
=(z-a)(z+a)
$
where
$a = \sqrt{2i}
=1+i
$
since
$(1+i)^2
=1+2i-1 = 2i
$.

The second one
just uses the quadratic formula,
which works for
complex as well as real coefficients,
to solve
$z^2 − 3iz − 3 + i
= 0
$.
If the roots are
$u$ and $v$,
then
$z^2 − 3iz − 3 + i
= (z-u)(z-v)
$.

(This was added later)

Using the quadratic formula,
the roots are

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{3i\pm\sqrt{(-3i)^2-4(-3+i)}}{2}
&=\dfrac{3i\pm\sqrt{-9+12-4i}}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{3i\pm\sqrt{3-4i}}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{3i\pm(2-i)}{2}
\qquad\text{since }\sqrt{3-4i} = 2-i\\
&=\dfrac{3i+(2-i), 3i-(2-i)}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{2+2i, -2+4i}{2}\\
&=1+i, -1+2i\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: There is a typo in $z^2-a$ :)

Comment: $\sqrt{3-4i}=2-i$.....brrrrrrr

Comment: In your post, 

$$ /sqrt{2i} =1+i $$ since $$ (1+i)^2=1+2i−1=2i $$ $$ /sqrt{3-4i}=2-i $$

Do you know these from repetition? or is there a method besides the quad formula.

Comment: Solve $(a+bi)^2 = c+di$. Equate real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 1):

If we are trying to factor $p(z) = z^2 - 2i$ we can determine the factorization by finding the zeros of the polynomial.

If $p(z) = 0$ then $z^2 = 2i$. Thus $|z| = \sqrt{2}$. Writing $z=\sqrt{2} e^{i\theta}$ we have $e^{i2\theta} = e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}}$. This yields $$\cos(2\theta) + i \sin(2\theta) = \cos(\pi/2) + i \sin(\pi/2).$$

Now if we restrict $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi]$, we find the solutions $\theta = \pi/4$ and $\theta = -\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

This means $p(\sqrt{2} e^{i  \pi/4} ) = 0$ and $p(\sqrt{2} e^{-i\frac{3\pi}{4}})$, and since it is monic, it can be factored as $$(z- \sqrt{2} e^{i\pi/4}) ( z - \sqrt{2} e^{-i3\pi/4}).$$

Finally $\sqrt{2} e^{i \pi/4} = \sqrt{2} ( \cos(\pi/4) + i \sin(\pi/4) ) = 1 + i$, and $\sqrt{2} e^{i3\pi/4} = -1-i$.